# Red Hat Configuration of Tomcat 8 - ${JAVA_OPTS} keyword not recognized

Tags: rhel, configuration, tomcat

I'm trying to configure `tomcat8` on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7. I get the configuration file from a Debian version (that I have set up), which is:

```
[...]

JAVA_OPTS='-Djava.awt.headless=true'
JAVA_OPTS='${JAVA_OPTS} -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8'
JAVA_OPTS='${JAVA_OPTS} -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC'

# memory
JAVA_OPTS='${JAVA_OPTS} -Xmx1024m -Xm1024m'

# logging
JAVA_OPTS='${JAVA_OPTS} -Dlogback.configurationFile=$CATALINA_BASE/conf/logback.xml'

[...]
```

With Red Hat this configuration doesn't work; I get this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class ${JAVA_OPTS}
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ${JAVA_OPTS}
```

But when I erase the `${JAVA_OPTS}` and concatenates the `JAVA_OPTS` on a single line:

```
JAVA_OPTS='-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Xmx1024m -Xm1024m' -Dlogback.configurationFile=$CATALINA_BASE/conf/logback.xml'
```

It works.

I've also tried to replace `${JAVA_OPTS}` with `$JAVA_OPTS`, %JAVA_OPTS%. Do you have any idea why `tomcat8` is not recognizing the `${JAVA_OPTS}`?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this configuration file supposed to be a shell script?

Comment: Mmmh... good question. Maybe that the thing; in `Debian` it can be written as a shell script while in `rhel` not. Could it be possible?

Comment: If it is, try using double quotes instead of single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes tell shell not to interpret the commands/variables inside. So you have no expand/interpret `${JAVA_OPTS}` construction. Try to make it on this way (with double quotes):

```
[...]

JAVA_OPTS='-Djava.awt.headless=true'
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"

# memory
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Xmx1024m -Xm1024m"

# logging
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Dlogback.configurationFile=$CATALINA_BASE/conf/logback.xml"

[...]
```

Also AFAIK on contemporary versions of java you should use `-Xms` instead of `-Xm`

Comment: I've tested with double quotes but I get the same error as before.

Comment: @BastianNanchen, so you have is somewhere else with single quotes, check it

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your phrase; are you insinuating that there is an existing `JAVA_OPTS` statement with single-quote?

Comment: @BastianNanchen, correct.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I've replaced all the single-quotes with double ones.